# Tim has two ways to try to win a money: Win at a lottery with a chance of $1$ in $300$ million. Roll a fair six-sided die ...

Tags: probability

Probability allows for the quantification of extremely rare events. For example, suppose Tim has two ways to try to win a large sum of money:

Win at a lottery with a chance of $1$ in $300$ million.

Roll a fair six-sided die $20$ times and roll all $6$s.

Which winning event is more likely to happen?

I am getting confused how did we get $10^15$ , when we were discussing about $3.10^8$.

[image]

Comment: what attempt you have made???

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What are your thoughts about this problem? What have you tried, or where do you think would be a good place to start?

Comment: Sir, I have edited the question to make you all understand my real problem.Sorry for not being appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it should have added at the end: $$6^{20} = 1296^5 > {1000^5} = (10^3)^5 = 10^{15} >\color{red}{3*10^8} $$

It is merely for comparison of size difference to show that $6^{20}$ is indeed larger than $3*10^8$. And if that's the case, then when we flip them into fractions, we see that $$\frac{1}{6^{20}} \lt \frac{1}{3*10^8}$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

1. What is the probability to roll a 6 in one roll of the regular 6-sided die?
2. If you make $20$ independent rolls, what is the probability of rolling a 6 in all of them?
3. Can you compare that probability to $1/(3 \times 10^8)$?

Comment: Thank you sir, but I am facing problem to understand how we get 10^15 , when we were discussing about 3.10^8 in our solution which I have attached now.